# How to solve mypy error "value of type row | none is not indexable" for pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, pyspark, mypy

Mypy throws the error "Value of type 'Row | None' is not indexable" for the line starting with "x=":

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

def somefunction(df: DataFrame, column_name: str) -> DataFrame:
    x = df.select(f.min(f.col(column_name))).first()[0] 
    return df.withColumn('newcolumn', f.col(column_name) + x)
```

How can I add a type check that passes mypy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df.select(...)` returns a value of type `Row | None`, which means the actual return value might be a `Row`, or it might be `None`. You can't index `None`, so you can't index a value of type `Row | None` until you establish that it definitely isn't `None`. (Essentially, the interface of a union type is the *intersection* of the individual types: you can only do with `A | B` what you can do to `A` *and* `B`.)

One way to do that is to use type narrowing: by checking if the return value is `None`, you can branch into code where the static type is `NoneType`, or into code where the static type is `Row`.

```
# reveal_type(result) == Row | None
result = df.select(f.min(f.col(column_name))).first()

if result is None:
    # reveal_type(result) == None
    do what needs to be done if no row is returned
else:
    # reveal_type(result) == Row
    x = result[0]
    return df.withColumn('new column', f.col(column_name) + x)
```

*You* might know that the particular argument to `df.select` *cannot* fail, but `mypy` does not.

---

Another option, if you are *absolutely* sure you will get a `Row` back, is to use `cast` to let `mypy` in on the secret.

```
x = typing.cast(Row, df.select(...))[0]
return df.withColumn(...)
```

This is risky, though. `mypy` will believe the `cast`, and if `df.select(...)` *does* return `None`, you'll get a runtime error even though `mypy` says it's OK.